# Can I disable CMD-TAB?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, screen-sharing, karabiner

I'm looking for a way to disable <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> and set up some other key chord to accomplish the same app-switching function (but without mapping that key chord to <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd>).

I use native Screen Sharing regularly and sometimes when I'm using a VPN (with GlobalProtect), the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> key gets interpreted locally rather than on the remote machine. If I turn off the VPN, then I can't do the screen sharing.

I've explored use of key mapping techniques, using Karabiner-Elements in particular, but if I disable <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> at the keyboard level, I can't send it to the remote system. If I map it to some other key combination, it gets mapped prior to going to the remote system. If app switching and its mapping to <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> would just appear with all the other keyboard shortcuts in System Preferences, this wouldn't be a problem.

I could work around this by setting up key mappings on the remote systems as well, but since I have this problem with many systems and I don't personally control some of those systems, I'd really like a solution that doesn't require a modification to the remote systems.

Comment: If these are all Macs that you're connecting to, then you might want to look at something like ARD (Apple Remote Desktop) or even a dedicated app like TeamViewer that has keybindings that you can set that only go to the remote.